# Android text to speech not working on mobile

Tags: android

i am having problem in text to speech. have this code in java class

```
package com.techblogon.loginexample;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class listenActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (tts!=null) {
            String text = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
            if (text!=null) {
                if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
                    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int code) {
        if (code==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        } else {
            tts = null;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to initialize TTS engine.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (tts!=null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

and xml file has this code

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".listenActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TTS Demonstration" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="Say It" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Hello world!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but issue is when i click button no sound heard on my mobile. does i need any permission for that
any help
Many thanks

Comment: Did you atleast validate that you are sending some text to your tts request?

Comment: yes its sending text to tts but it doesnot speak the text

Comment: its not passing any thing to tts even if i left textbox empty it doesnot throw an error

Comment: i am using s4 device